# Wishing to develop my own music library program

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to come up with a way of developing a folder / library program for my my music collection that will display my music in order and also have the name / image under the song.
This will be a desktop program on my Windows system. I am doing this for college and not sure exactly which languages to use. I have been learning Objective C and C. I know most web languages such as PHP to Javascript. Though this is my first shot at actual " software " development.

I am using dev c++ as my main program. 
I am not trying to program my own actual mp3 player, I just wish to catalog all my media files in a stylish app and when we hit play, it shall pass it off to itunes or media player to play.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What Jon Reid said, and also Objective C won't help you much on Windows.  That being said, I'd start with Visual Studio (as far as I know you can download an "Express" or Trial edition from Microsoft) and start playing around with the User Interface and programming UI.  Then I'd worry about dealing with the file system and such.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is a good choice, as it's a very powerful and popular GUI framework.  They have all sorts of out-of-the-box widgets for browsing the filesystem, displaying pretty lists, etc.. The learning curve is a little steeper than some but IMO the effort is well worth it. http://qt.nokia.com/products/platform/qt-for-windows/